# Postgres Docker container failed to start with psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" f

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am working on a docker container which initialises postgre sql db from a sql dump file.However while running the init script I am facing below exception .

```
Attaching to postgres
postgres | psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
postgres |      Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
postgres exited with code 2
```

**DockerFile:**

```
FROM postgres:latest

## Some utilities
RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y build-essential libfuse-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libxml2-dev pkg-config libssl-dev mime-support automake libtool wget tar git unzip
RUN apt-get install lsb-release -y  && apt-get install zip -y && apt-get install vim -y

## Install S3 Fuse
RUN rm -rf /usr/src/s3fs-fuse
RUN git clone https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse/ /usr/src/s3fs-fuse
WORKDIR /usr/src/s3fs-fuse 
RUN ./autogen.sh && ./configure && make && make install

## Create folder
RUN mkdir /data
WORKDIR /data
RUN mkdir out

## change workdir to /
WORKDIR /

RUN rm -rf 1-restore.sh
ADD docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/1-restore.sh 1-restore.sh
RUN chmod 777 1-restore.sh 
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "1-restore.sh" ]
```

Below is my init Shell script file:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

export PGPASSWORD=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD

psql  -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" --dbname "$POSTGRES_DB" < $DUMP_FILE
set -e

export PGPASSWORD=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD

psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" --dbname "$POSTGRES_DB" <<-EOSQL
  SET client_encoding TO 'UTF8';
  \t
  \a
  \o $OUT_FOLDER/export_json.sql;
  SELECT '\o $OUT_FOLDER/' || table_name || '.json;' || E'\n' || 'SELECT row_to_json(r) FROM "' || table_name || '" AS r;'
  FROM information_schema.tables
  WHERE table_schema = 'public'
  ORDER BY table_name;
  \i $OUT_FOLDER/export_json.sql;
EOSQL

rm $OUT_FOLDER/export_json.sql

echo ""TestMessage">>test.txt
```

I checked the other so ans but nothing yet worked for me .

Comment: Anything you set as `ENTRYPOINT` (or `CMD`) runs _instead of_ the normal container process; you're trying to run your initialization script as the main container process, without also running the database that's being initialized.

Comment: You should be able to put the `$DUMP_FILE` in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` and the standard `postgres` image will know how to load it, without this shell-script wrapper.

Comment: I think you have to run postgres server itself. Try to look at the official Dockerfile  here https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/c6329e3bf217ca53fbb78d27d756f95498cb143f/14/bullseye/Dockerfile there is `CMD ["postgres"]` for the postgres start. You have overwrite it with your ENTRYPOINT without this command.

Comment: @DavidMaze That i tried it works .I want it to be separate as I want to execute some   part of script which are not dependent on init of db .For those I want a custom script

Comment: @czende Thanks .I will check that